# Query DBpedia for countries with human development index

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to query for all Countries in DBpedia and get their human development index. 
The query I am trying is:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?Country a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> .
?Country <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/humanDevelopmentIndex> ?humanDevelopmentIndex .
}
LIMIT 1000
```

Would anyone be able to explain why this query isn't returning any results? It seems straightforward to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting anything back because apparently, none of the countries in DBpedia actually have a `humanDevelopmentIndex` property associated with them.

You can verify this for yourself. If you simplify your query to just get back countries:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?Country a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> .
}
LIMIT 1000
```

You will get back a list of countries, so clearly it is the addition of the other property pattern that causes the query to not match any results. Also, if you take a look at the data for, for example, [Austrialia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Australia) in DBPedia, you will not find the property you want there.

The reason it doesn't appear is that the data you want is probably located in the `ontology_infobox_properties` or the `ontology_infobox_properties_specific` dataset. These are [not exposed in the public endpoint](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DatasetsLoaded), but you can [download them](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems as if its named 'hdi' on that Australian page, so the data is indeed there. I must just be extracting it incorrectly.

Comment: @GuyEvans, I think is 'hdi' is the less specific version of the property you're after. See my updated answer for my (unconfirmed) suspicion on why the 'humanDevelopmentIndex` property does not appear.

Comment: I think you're right, I forgot that it wasn't all loaded. Thanks.